# Display KML (or other "raw data" file) nicely in WP?

Tags: formatting

I want to display this file:

http://data.barrycarter.info/aprswx.txt

on wordpress.barrycarter.info, but all my attempts fail because of 
preprocessing:

http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/test-kml-fail

(use "view source" to see what parts of the file WP "hides" from view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a plugin like syntax highlighter evolved. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Or wrap it in `<pre>` or `<code>` tags.

Comment: <pre><code> didn't work, but <pre><code><textarea> did. I was tempted to use iframe, but sense this is cleaner.